# Annoying this.refresh() is not a function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, refresh

Here is the solution to my problem. I am able to make a field appear, enter a new value, click the field again and make the field disappear with the new value. The Firefox error console complains every time that this.refresh() is not a function.

How do I get rid of the this.refresh() is not a function error so that I can clear my Firefox console and look for errors that actually cause problems?

```
var gotIt='no'

function askName(x)
 {if(gotIt=='yes')
   {response=this.name
    characters[x].setName(response)
    gotIt='no'
   }
  else
   {gotIt='no'
    this.name=characters[x].name
    response="<input onClick=_setName(this.value) size=10 type=text value="+this.name+">"
    characters[x].setName(response)
   }
 }
function _setName(x)
 {this.name=x
  this.refresh()
  gotIt='yes'
 }
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to?  When you call the "_setName()" function, you're not doing so in a way that `this` will end up bound to anything (other than the global object).  What "refresh()" function are you trying to call?

Comment: Thanks Pointy, I'm actually trying to refresh the field so that the value that I enter is captured.

Comment: @ren1999: Refresh the field??

Comment: Yes. When I first click on the bold text that has the name "Braveheart" for example, a field appears with the word Braveheart in it. Then I change the word from Braveheart to Braveheart2 and click it again. The field disappears and Braveheart2 is in bold text. This requires a refresh function or the value is not updated.

Comment: @ren1999: There is no such function in JavaScript unless you defined one yourself.

Comment: `this` in `this.refresh()` would be pointing to the same object as `_setName` is called on but you show no code for that objects definition. What data will there be in `characters[n]`?

Comment: ren1999: I've not heard of a refresh being necessary within Javascript.  Generally speaking, if you make changes to the DOM, they happen straight away.

Comment: If anybody wants to see the program I'm trying to improve, it is here. See the annoying alert boxes? I want to be able to create fields in each value and hide them. http://www.asmor.com/scripts/CombatTracker/combattracker.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost everything in your code is wrong, the following code do what you need. If you want to understand javascript you need to strive.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onload = function () {
                var input = document.createElement ("input");
                var span = document.getElementsByTagName ("span")[0];

                input.addEventListener ("blur", function () {
                    span.innerHTML = this.value;
                }, false);

                span.addEventListener ("click", function () {
                    if (this.getElementsByTagName ("input").length === 0) {
                        input.value = this.textContent;

                        this.innerHTML = "";

                        this.appendChild (input);

                        input.focus ();
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        </script>

        <style>
            span {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>

        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span>Braveheart</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Now if I have three cloned forms, Braveheart, Bob and Frank all contained in characters[x].name. How can I use this function to change all three values separately? Also, if I add a new character, I want to be able to change the name of the 4th character in the same way.